# Maven archetype: String replacement not working

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm building a maven archetype. And filename substitution is working fine. For instance I have a file named `__`artifactd`__`-log4j.xml that when generated is replaced fine. But, one of the xml files, a spring context file, which references it, its not being replaced:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```xml
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />


<bean id="log4jConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"></property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"></property>
     <property name="arguments">
     <list>
        <value>classpath:${artifactId}-log4j.xml</value>
        <value>5000</value>
     </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

for some reason the token ${artifactId} inside the xml file is never replaced. My *archetype-metadata.xml*

```xml
 <modules>
<module id="${rootArtifactId}-services" dir="__rootArtifactId__-services" name="${rootArtifactId}-services">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.jsp</include>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</module>
```

The spring-file is under src/main/resources, and since fileSet is set to filtered it should have being replaced by velocity right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `${project.artifactId}`? According to the [Maven Reference Book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html), all project properties have the `project` prefix.

Comment: Yes. That does not work as well. It really seems that maven is just ignoring any file to be processed as templates. I tried maven 3.0.3 and 3.0.4. Same stuff. In some files I have some velocity macros, and they just get copied over, which means maven is not processing the files marked to be filtered, its just copying them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was changing the template project I've used from mvn archetype:create-from-project instead of the generated-resources that's the reason.

So I ended having VLT doubled escaped.

Fixed :D

Comment: Can you please explain this?  I know you start out with a project, do "create-from-project" on it, then cd to the target/generated-sources/archetype directory and then build it, but after that you lost me.